# Minus Year from Date original: 20140320 Android

Tags: java, android

Example `(Date) btDate.getTag() = 20140320;`

How can I substract a year from 20140320 and set the result as date format.
So that e.g, 20140320  result = 20130320

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it my following customized method,

```
private String getSubStractYear ( String date )
{
    try
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ( "yyyyMMdd" );
        Date myDate = sdf.parse(date);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(myDate);
        calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR , -1 );

        return ( sdf.format( calendar.getTime() ) );
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

Input : 20140320
Output : 20130320

Comment: @Dimitri, did you try my answer ?

Answer (score -1):

In Java 8 you can use the new Date/Time classes:

Your function:

```
private String substractYears(final String dateFrom, final int yearsToSubstract) {
    final DateTimeFormatter dtf  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
    final LocalDate         date = LocalDate.parse(dateFrom, dtf);       

    return dtf.format(date.minusYears(yearsToSubstract));
}
```

Example use:

```
System.out.printf("%s\n", substractYears("20140302", 1));
```

That will print: `20130302`